# how can I commit mid workflow with cosmwasm

Tags: rust, cosmwasm

in my contract, I'm making a call to an AMM module through a submessage. Once this submessage call is successful, I want my contract to send a token to the user using the Bank module. How can I ensure that the transaction is committed successfully after the swap, so that my contract holds the token after the swap?

So i try to send the token directly after calling the amm module but since the transaction is not resolve my contract doesn't have the token yet to send them to the user